# How can you express when somebody makes a claim more solid?

Tags: expressions, german

I would like to express that somebody gives a reason to believe a claim. Something among the lines

1. They fortify their claim by ...
2. They back their claim up by ...
3. They support their claim by ...

In German, I would say

> Sie **untermauern** ihre Behauptung mit ...

How can I say this in English?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of your choices work well in academic and technical settings.  *Support* is by far the most applicable term and, as noted in a comment below, is preferred. If you want to take advantage of subtle differences in the meanings of these terms:

- > They *support* their claim by ...
  >
  > Support for a claim covers it all—the basis for a claim, the reasoning behind its conclusions, and evidence of its validity.
- > They *back* their claim by ...
  >
  > [No need to say "back their claim *up* by ...," as in your example, or "back *up* their claim by ...."]
  >
  > To back a claim is to provide reasoning and supporting evidence intended to withstand broad counterargument.
  >
  > The term [*bolster*, as noted in another answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/78616/28626), is an excellent alternative to *back*.
  >
  > The term *substantiate*, a translation of your German word *untermauern*, is itself a common alternative to *back* when presenting supporting evidence.
- > They *fortify* their *reasoning* by ...
  >
  > To fortify a line of reasoning is to protect it against a specific anticipated counterargument.
  >
  > The term *reinforce* is preferred over *fortify.*

The distinctions made here are minor in most contexts.

Comment: +1. I believe the first is more common though.

Comment: I disagree that "back up their claim" isn't acceptable (unless you were just objecting to the word order of "back their claim up"?): [it's actually more common than just "back"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=back+their+claim%2Cback+up+their+claim&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cback%20their%20claim%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cback%20up%20their%20claim%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Agreed and revised but not encouraged.

Comment: (Native AmE) I've never heard "fortify a claim" except in the sense of a legal claim. (I did just google and find an occurrence of it outside of law, though.)

Comment: Noted well and revised to "fortify their reasoning."

Comment: +1 "Back up" is definitely the first thing I thought of (*with* "up"), but "support" might be better for a formal setting. "Fortify" sounds rather odd.

Answer (score 2):

Another word you might consider is ***bolster***. It's a verb meaning "[to strengthen or support](http://onelook.com/?w=bolster)."

This verb is often paired up with the noun *claim*, as in these news articles:

> A number of studies published in reputable journals and backed by the beverage industry have sought to **bolster the claim** that artificially sweetened beverages can prevent a person from packing on extra pounds. ([Newsweek](http://www.newsweek.com/big-beverage-still-wants-you-think-soft-drinks-are-healthy-362126))
>
> He also claimed that notebooks were doctored to **bolster the claim** that Brown wrote the script. ([Variety](http://variety.com/2014/biz/news/federal-judge-inclined-to-dismiss-trouble-with-the-curve-case-1201118785/))
>
> To **bolster the claim** that the "loss" wasn't that bad, The Times points out that Google sold Motorola Home for $2.4 billion and is keeping most of Motorola's patents. ([Mashable](http://mashable.com/2014/01/30/no-matter-how-you-slice-it-google-lost-on-motorola/#l58mGq50lgqC))